# Remove characters from a string

Tags: javascript, string

What are the different ways I can remove characters from a string in JavaScript?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I remove a character from a string using Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9932957/how-can-i-remove-a-character-from-a-string-using-javascript)

Answer (score 100):

Using `replace()` with regular expressions is the most flexible/powerful.  It's also the only way to globally replace every instance of a search pattern in JavaScript.  The non-regex variant of `replace()` will only replace the first instance.

For example:

```
var str = "foo gar gaz";

// returns: "foo bar gaz"
str.replace('g', 'b');

// returns: "foo bar baz"
str = str.replace(/g/gi, 'b');
```

In the latter example, the trailing `/gi` indicates case-insensitivity and global replacement (meaning that not just the first instance should be replaced), which is what you typically want when you're replacing in strings.

To *remove* characters, use an empty string as the replacement:

```
var str = "foo bar baz";

// returns: "foo r z"
str.replace(/ba/gi, '');
```

Comment: Good answer. By the way, `str.replace('g', 'b');` does not work itself. Using `str = str.replace('g', 'b');` would make the answer better.

Answer (score 48):

**ONELINER** which remove characters LIST (more than one at once) - for example remove `+,-, ,(,)` from telephone number:

```
var str = "+(48) 123-456-789".replace(/[-+()\s]/g, '');  // result: "48123456789"
```

We use regular expression `[-+()\s]` where we put unwanted characters between `[` and `]`

(the "`\s`" is 'space' character escape - for more info google 'character escapes in in regexp')

Comment: You can achieve the same result regarding the example with the telephone number with a simpler and more powerful regexp:

```var str = "+(48) 123-456-789".replace(/[\D]/g, ''); // result: "48123456789"```

Answer (score 14):

I know this is old but if you do a split then join it will remove all occurrences of a particular character ie:

```
var str = theText.split('A').join('')
```

will remove all occurrences of 'A' from the string, obviously it's not case sensitive

Comment: Perfect.  If you need something that is easy to read.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) function.

```
str.replace(regexp|substr, newSubstr|function)
```

Answer (score 3):

Another method that no one has talked about so far is the substr method to produce strings out of another string...this is useful if your string has defined length and the characters your removing are on either end of the string...or within some "static dimension" of the string.

Answer (score 1):

You may remove a single occurrence of a character from a string with something like the following:

```js
const removeChar = (str: string, charToBeRemoved: string) => {
    const charIndex: number = str.indexOf(charToBeRemoved);
    let part1 = str.slice(0, charIdx);
    let part2 = str.slice(charIdx + 1, str.length);
    return part1 + part2;
  };
```

Remove the type decorators if you prefer to use pure JavaScript.

Comment: The question is not about Typescript.