# Remove "$" from form input field

Tags: jquery

I am working on a site that is using a form to accept donations for their foundation.  The payment gateway returns an error if a "$" is included with the actual dollar amount.

Is there an easy way to strip the "$" out of the input field before submitting the form if they type one in?

Thanks.

Comment: How is the data submitted? In any case, have a look at [Remove characters from a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4846978/remove-characters-from-a-string)

Comment: Use `.replace(/[^\d.]/g,"")`. This function removes each character, except for digits and dots.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('#donationform').submit(function() {
  //get amount value
  var CurrencyField = $("input[name='chargetotal']").val()
  //return amount without $
  $("input[name='chargetotal']").val( CurrencyField.replace('$', '') );
});
```

Should do the trick :)

Comment: Marco, do I change the #target to the ID of the form?

Comment: Yes #target is the id of the form, and #amount is the id/class of your input field with the $ amount

Comment: Marco, I changed #target to #donationform -- this form is passing the dollar amount with a name="chargetotal"

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rsBus/ .. shouldnt matter since you change it, before page submit. Do you have firebug, or use a developer  tool? Then you can see if it is changed before submit :)

Comment: Marco, I finally got it to work -- although now when I hit submit -- the "$" is removed -- but the form doesn't submit.

Comment: You didnt copy the return false; from jsfiddle? That disables the submit, the reason i used it, was for watching the effect. So remove it if you copied it :) What was wrong?

Comment: Fixed.  I'm a rookie.  Thanks for going back and forth with me on this.  Works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('form').submit(function() {

    $('input[type=text]', this).each(function() {
        $(this).val( $(this).val().replace(/\$/g, '') );
    });

    return true;
});
```

Comment: Mike, tried your method -- do I need to change 'form' to the ID of the form?  Also -- would I change input[type-text] to input[name='chargetotal'] ? doesn't seem to be working

Comment: Yes. You'd want to change form to a selector appropriate for the form you are targeting. Also, the reason I did type=text is to have it go against all text fields. Don't add quote marks in selector.

Answer (score 1):

on client-side (jquery/javascript)

```
var fieldvalue = {...get from input field...};
fieldvalue = fieldvalue.replace(/\$/,"");
```

on server-side (php, after submitting)

```
$fieldvalue = $_POST['fieldname'];
$fieldvalue = str_replace("$", "", $fieldvalue);
```

Answer (score 0):

on submission, use the "[replace](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp)" method on the contents of the field before returning true.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`String.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) to remove any substring from a string:

```
var amount = $('#amount').val().replace('$', '');
```

will make `amount` contain the value of the form field with `id="amount"` without the first dollar sign in it.