# Remove unwanted characters from a string

Tags: javascript

I want to remove the characters `[` and `]` inside a variable. How can I do this? My variable is something similar to this one:

```
var str = "[this][is][a][string]";
```

Any suggestion is very much appreciated!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove characters from a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4846978/remove-characters-from-a-string)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Behold the power of regular expressions:

```
str = str.replace(/[\]\[]/g,'');
```

Comment: thank you for the quick reply! ^^.. i have an additional question though. how can i remove "[" and "]" + the string inside it except for the last string in my variable(which is "string").. im new to jQuery regular expression

Comment: @unknown I'm not clear on  what you mean. I would suggest familiarizing yourself with regular expressions, or else just parse the string using `str.split()` to find what you want.

Answer (score 0):

the fastest way

```
function replaceAll(string, token, newtoken) {
    while (string.indexOf(token) != -1) {
        string = string.replace(token, newtoken);
    }
    return string;
}
```

All you need to do is this...

```
var str = "[this][is][a][string]";

srt=replaceAll(str,'[','');    //remove "["

str=replaceAll(str,']','');    //remove "]"
```