# Remove a character at a certain position in a string - javascript

Tags: javascript, string

Is there an easy way to remove the character at a certain position in javascript?

e.g. if I have the string `"Hello World"`, can I remove the character at position 3?

the result I would be looking for would the following:

```
"Helo World"
```

This question isn't a duplicate of [How can I remove a character from a string using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9932957), because this one is about removing the character at a specific position, and that question is about removing all instances of a character.

Comment: I did, but I can't have looked very hard

Comment: This isn't a duplicate. This question is about removing an known character from a certain position. The duplicate is about removing a known character from an arbitrary position.

Comment: @MT0 Nope. This question is about removing the character at a particular index - and that question is about removing instances of a particular character from a string.

Comment: @starbeamrainbowlabs No, it is an exact duplicate; the linked question is about removing the 4th character (which just happens to also always be an `r`). The [accepted answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11116529/1509264) is identical to the [2nd highest voted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9933072/1509264) on that question.

Answer (score 161, accepted):

It depends how *easy* you find the following, which uses simple String methods (in this case [`slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice)).

```js
var str = "Hello World";
str = str.slice(0, 3) + str.slice(4);
console.log(str)
```

Comment: Thank You! I knew that there would be a simple solution. I didn't think of that :-)

Comment: @Zon: Exactly, and that's the idea. When coupled with `+ str.slice(4);`, you end up removing the 3rd character (zero indexed) in the string `str`. `str.slice(0, 3) + str.slice(4) // Helo World`

Comment: Just to put my dollar: str.slice(0, 3) gives 'Hel' (take from 1st to 3rd symbol);
str.slice(4) gives 'o World' (take all after 4th symbol); you can also set cutting borders like this: str.slice(0, -6) to get 'Hello'.

Comment: function removeByIndex(aStr,index){
 if(index==aStr.length-1){
  return aStr.slice(0,aStr.length-1);
 }
 else{
   return aStr.slice(0,index)+aStr.slice(index+1);
 }
}
function myFunction() {
  var str = "abc"; 
  var res =removeByIndex(str,2);
  console.log(res);
}

Answer (score 22):

You can try it this way:

```
var str = "Hello World";
var position = 6; // its 1 based
var newStr = str.substring(0, position - 1) + str.substring(position, str.length);
alert(newStr);
```

Here is a live example: http://jsbin.com/ogagaq

Comment: What if the postion variable gets the value 0? The first character is not deleted.

Comment: @GeorgeSiggouroglou Thanks for pointing out, actually the position variable is 1 based(I commented 0). Just fixed the comment.

Answer (score 19):

Turn the string into array, cut a character at specified index and turn back to string

```
let str = 'Hello World'.split('')

str.splice(3, 1)
str = str.join('')

// str = 'Helo World'.
```

Comment: You could even use do `[...'Hello world!'].splice(3, 1).join('')`.

Comment: @AminNAIRI I'm afraid it won't work.

Answer (score 9):

If you omit the particular index character then use this method

```
function removeByIndex(str,index) {
      return str.slice(0,index) + str.slice(index+1);
}
    
var str = "Hello world", index=3;
console.log(removeByIndex(str,index));

// Output: "Helo world"
```

Comment: What if index=0?

Comment: @Ali I got the issue, Thanks for Inform me. I  Update the code.

Comment: I believe this also fails for index = 1, removes index 0 instead

Comment: @Erick misteck corrected thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 4):

```
    var str = 'Hello World';
                str = setCharAt(str, 3, '');
                alert(str);

function setCharAt(str, index, chr)
        {
            if (index > str.length - 1) return str;
            return str.substr(0, index) + chr + str.substr(index + 1);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `substring()` method. ex,

```
var x = "Hello world"
var x = x.substring(0, i) + 'h' + x.substring(i+1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi starbeamrainbowlabs ,

You can do this with the following:

```
var oldValue = "pic quality, hello" ;
var newValue =  "hello";
var oldValueLength = oldValue.length ;
var newValueLength = newValue.length ;
var from = oldValue.search(newValue) ;
var to = from + newValueLength ;
var nes = oldValue.substr(0,from) + oldValue.substr(to,oldValueLength);
console.log(nes);
```

I tested this in my javascript console so you can also check this out
Thanks

Answer (score -1):

```
var str = 'Hello World',
    i = 3,
    result = str.substr(0, i-1)+str.substring(i);

alert(result);
```

Value of `i` should not be less then `1`.

Comment: What's `i`? Why should it not be less than 1 instead of 0?