# How can I remove letters from a string in javascript and return the remainder of the string?

Tags: javascript

if I have :

```
   var string = "Something";
```

and I want to remove [e]

and get:

```
   string = "Somthing";
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Do you want to remove every instance of the letter `e`, a single instance of the letter `e`, or any character appearing at index 3?

Comment: You've done it already. Assign it again without `e`, then you will have your job done. Search for "string replace javascript" and you'll be amazed by the tremendous amount of resources at your hands to achieve what you've set out to achieve.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/replacing-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript

Comment: I want to remove the character appearing at index 3

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove a character at a certain position in a string - javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11116501/remove-a-character-at-a-certain-position-in-a-string-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string = string.replace(/\e/g, '');
```

should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

To access various letters in the array, you can use `charAt()`:

```
for(var i = 0; i < string.length; i++){
  console.log(string.charAt(i));
}
```

To find the `e`:

```
for(var i = 0; i < string.length; i++){
  if(string.charAt(i) === `e`){
    console.log("found an e");
  }
}
```

To remove the 'e':

```
var string = "something";
var arr = string.split(''); //["s", "o", "m", "e", "t", "h", "i", "n", "g"]
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
  if(arr[i] === 'e'){
    arr.splice(i,1);
  }
}

arr.join('');   //"somthing"
```