# Remove character from string using javascript

Tags: javascript

i have comma separated string like

`var test = 1,3,4,5,6,`

i want to remove particular character from this string using java script

can anyone suggests me?

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: you want to remove the separator or some number in your string? What do you want to output: an array or a string?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript - remove character from a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9932957/javascript-remove-character-from-a-string)

Answer (score 42):

JavaScript strings provide you with [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method which takes as a parameter a string of which the first instance is replaced or a `RegEx`, which if being global, replaces all instances.

Example:

```
var str = 'aba';
str.replace('a', ''); // results in 'ba'
str.replace(/a/g, ''); // results in 'b'
```

If you alert str - you will get back the same original string cause strings are immutable.
You will need to assign it back to the string :

```
str = str.replace('a', '');
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer It really helped me.

Answer (score 6):

Use `replace` and if you want to remove multiple occurrence of the character use

replace like this

```
var test = "1,3,4,5,6,";
var newTest = test.replace(/,/g, '-');
```

here newTest will became `"1-3-4-5-6-"`

Answer (score 4):

you can make use of JavaScript `replace()` Method

```
var str="Visit Microsoft!";
var n=str.replace("Microsoft","My Blog");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var test = '1,3,4,5,6';​​

//to remove character
document.write(test.replace(/,/g, '')); 

//to remove number
function removeNum(string, val){
   var arr = string.split(',');
   for(var i in arr){
      if(arr[i] == val){
         arr.splice(i, 1);
         i--;
      }
  }            
 return arr.join(',');
}

var str = removeNum(test,3);    
document.write(str); // output 1,4,5,6
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also

> var test1 = test.split(',');
>
> delete test1[2];
>
> var test2 = test1.toString();

Have fun :)

Answer (score 0):

you can split the string by comma into an array and then remove the particular element [character or number or even string] from that array. once the element(s) removed, you can join the elements in the array into a string again

```
// Array Remove - By John Resig (MIT Licensed)
Array.prototype.remove = function(from, to) {
    var rest = this.slice((to || from) + 1 || this.length);
    this.length = from < 0 ? this.length + from : from;
    return this.push.apply(this, rest);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function

```
function removeComma(inputNumber,char='') {

        return inputNumber.replace(/,/g, char);
    }
```

**Update**

```
   function removeComma(inputNumber) {
        inputNumber = inputNumber.toString();
        return Number(inputNumber.replace(/,/g, ''));
    }
```