# Remove Coma in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

```
<input type="number" id="fname" name="fname">
<input type="submit" onclick="fun()" value="Submit">
```

```
  function fun(){
  var x= document.getElementById("fname").value;}
```

How to strip coma from it before any process start.
Help. It show Zero only nothing that is good.

Code Updated with full detail.

Problem for me is number type for coma , not doing any favor.

Other option look use type=text in HTML. Problem with me to import from HTML to java-script. and value

https://codepen.io/puneetxp/pen/PoPMXEQ

Thanks guys for fast help.

I Found the Solution threw hint.

```
 <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname">
 var x= document.getElementById("fname").value.replace(/,/g, '');
```

Turn Out the Type number can't handle , (comas).
But still anybody know it can work with number then let me know.

Comment: Use a str.replace(/,/g,'') to remove the comma.  Coma is a state of not being awake.

Comment: I have no clue what you are asking.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove character from string using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13303479/remove-character-from-string-using-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

```
var stringWithoutCommas = x.replace(/,/g," ");
```

Comment: Note that this adds spaces in place of the commas, probably not the intent.

Comment: input type="number" is good for this. It carry , in value in begin with

Answer (score 0):

the reason why it show only a zero is because you did not do the `oninput=“function()”` <= when the user inputs something, the function in quotes is called, if you don’t put this, then when the user does input something nothing happens, this causes the `0` or `Null`

Comment: it have 2 line now. please look for me again.

Comment: thanks but nubmer type can't handle coma that is solved now.