# How i can remove character from a string?

Tags: javascript, php

I want to remove character from a string ex: `[\"lorem ipsum\"]` , i want like  `lorem ipsum`  without this characters `[\" \"]`.

**how i can do this in `javascript` or `PHP`  ?**

Comment: In `JavaSctip` or `PHP` ?

Comment: in javascript or PHP

Comment: In which language you want the solution ?

Comment: i which in javascript

Comment: Are you asking how to remove any of the characters `[\"]` if they appear anywhere in the string, or just the combinations of `[\"` and `\"]` if they appear at the start and the end? Or are you asking to remove everything *except* letters and spaces? Or...?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript - remove character from a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9932957/javascript-remove-character-from-a-string)

Comment: No just the combinations of `[\" and \"]` if they appear at the start and the end.

Answer (score 2):

**In javascript**

```
var str = "[\"lorem ipsum\"]";
alert(str.replace(/[^a-zA-Z ]/g, ""));
```

**And in PHP**

```
$string = "[\"lorem ipsum\"]";
$result = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', ' ', $string);
echo $result;
```

Answer (score 0):

**JavaScript**

**If you want to remove this specific combination** `[\" \"]` just use the `replace` function:

```
mystring = mystring.replace('[\"','');
mystring = mystring.replace('\"]','');
```

**If you want to remove all non-alphanumeric chars:**

The following is the/a correct regex to strip non-alphanumeric chars from an input string:

```
mystring = mystring.replace(/\W/g, '')
```

Note that `\W` is the equivalent of `[^0-9a-zA-Z_]` - it includes the underscore character. To also remove underscores use e.g.:

```
mystring = mystring.replace(/[^0-9a-z]/gi, '')
```