# How to destructively remove characters from two points in a string?

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to remove the characters destructively from two points in a string, so when the string is called after the removal it would not include the removed characters.

### Example

var string = "I am a string";

I'd like to: remove (0, 7);

When I call string again it should return:

console.log(string) => string

### Example-2

var string = "I am a string";

I'd like to: remove (7, 10);

When I call string again it should return:

console.log(string) => I am a ing

Comment: Strings are immutable, you have to build a new string from the bits you want to keep, you can't just remove the bits you don't want (i.e. there's no equivalent for Array's *splice*).

Comment: Great point! I tried to remove 'destructively' from the title but I couldn't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [javascript substring](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp).

For your example use this:

```
var string = "I am a string";
console.log(string.substring(7));
```

**OUTPUTS**

```
string
```

**UPDATE**

For removing a portionof a string, you can do it by concating the first wanted characters with the last wanted characters, something like this:

```
var string = "I am a string";
console.log(string.substr(0, 5) + string.substr(7));
```

**OUTPUTS**

```
I am string
```

If you want to have a direct function for removing portions of strings, see [Ken White's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9933121/1889685) that uses `substr` instead of `substring`. The difference between `substr` and `substring` is in the second parameter, for `substring` is the index to stop and for `substr` the length to return. You can use something like this:

```
String.prototype.replaceAt = function(index, charcount) {
  return this.substr(0, index) + this.substr(index + charcount);
}

string.replaceAt(5, 2); // Outputs: "I am string"
```

Or if you want to use `start` and `end` like `(7, 10)`, then have a function like this:

```
String.prototype.removeAt = function(start, end) {
  return this.substr(0, start) + this.substr(end);
}

string.removeAt(7, 10); // Outputs: "I am a ing"
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I should of clarified that I'd also like to remove characters from the middle of a string. Post updated.

Comment: Note that [*substring*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-string.prototype.substring) and [*substr*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-string.prototype.substr) are subtly different. The first uses *start, end* parameters, the second *start, length*.

Comment: Great! Exactly what I was looking for, I'm surprised there isn't a method that does this.

Comment: Just one problem, as RobG pointed in comment... console.log(string), after 'removal', returns original variable.

Comment: @RobG yes I know. I got the `String.prototype.replaceAt` exactly as it is on Ken White's answer. I think it works quite well for such functionality, but I guess using `substring` here would be better since we have to deal with string indexes and not length.

Comment: Yes, that's true, but then you can assign the value to the string variable like this `string = string.removeAt(7, 10);`. It's pretty simple. I can update my answer if a so basic functionality needs clarification. We have the same functionality like `substring` or `substr` would work like, which both don't affect the string variable are called from, but return the result.

Comment: I was really just pointing out that the answer starts with a reference to *substring* and uses it in the first bit of code, but uses *substr* thereafter without making a note of it.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to just slice the front part and the back part and splice them back together:

```js
var string = "I am a string";
string = string.substring(0, 7) + string.substring(10);
console.log(string);
// => I am a ing
```