# React convert a string into element with sub and super scripts

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, string

I'm trying to make a functional component that basically converts ^ and _ characters in a string to sub and super scripts. Here are some examples.

```
'example_3' -> <h1>example<sub>3<sub/><h1/>
```

should start a tag at a '_' or '^' and close the tag at the next non-number character.

```
'another_1234Example' -> <h1>another<sub>1234<sub/>Example<h1/>
```

also should be able to work for any amount of numbers

```
'something^2else_34' -> <h1>something<sup>2<sub/>else<sub>34<sub/> <h1/>
```

Comment: When do you want to end it? You can replace the _ or ^ with a <sub>

Comment: At the next non number character- I'll make it clearer in the questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution 1 (over complicated):**

```js
const string = "another_1234Example_348jiwf_342";

console.log(
  (string.trim() + " ")
    .split("_")
    .join("<sub>")
    .split(/(?<=<sub>\d+)(?!\d)/g)
    .join("</sub>")
);
```

Split `_` this will return an array, join a `<sub>` after that. Than check with regex if it matches a number with a start `<sub>`.

Link to regex: https://regex101.com/r/RFkEQa/1

**Solution 2 (recommend):**

It's better to use replace for this kind of stuff. Referring to this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50463993/8273193

```js
const string = "another_1234Example_348jiwf_342";
console.log(string.replace(/(_\d+)/g, "<sub>$&</sub>").replace(/_/g, ""));
```

Comment: That works great in most cases: however it doesn't add the closing tag if the string ends with a number, and doesn't add one if there are multiple subscripts in the string

Comment: Oh didn't test that will update my answer

Comment: what about super scipts? same kind of thing, or is there a different regex expression needed?

Comment: Different regex https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35976910/regex-to-replace-all-superscript-numbers. You can combine them with the number one.

Comment: thanks! what about negative numbers (just out of curiosity).