# Are the two js statements always returning the same result? s.replace(/\t/g, '|') vs s.split('\t').join('|')

Tags: javascript

First:

```
var s = input_string.replace(/\t/g, '|');
```

Second:

```
var s = input_string.split('\t').join('|');
```

Is there any possibility that they could get different results?

Comment: The result will be the same. But in terms of performance replace is far more efficient. Also in terms of readability replace is clear and concise, while split/join is a bit less "direct". I wouldn't recommend the latter by any means unless you have a very specific reason for it. You can read more here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50463850/split-and-join-function-or-the-replace-function

Comment: Daniel, thanks for the ref.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `input_string` is a plain string, and that none of the build-in methods `String.prototype.replace`, `String.prototype.split`, `Array.prototype.join` have been tampered with - then no, `.replace` followed by `.join` in that matter will always produce the same output.

If you allow for the possibility that the methods have been patched, then all bets are off.

```js
String.prototype.replace = () => '';
console.log('foo'.replace(/\t/g, '|'));
```