# Remove everthing between two characters

Tags: javascript, regex, string

How would you remove everything between all instances of brackets like in
 `var item = '<p>1. Get this <a title= "Static Review"> </a> more text </p>'`

I've tried using the solution from [How can I remove a character from a string using Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9932957/how-can-i-remove-a-character-from-a-string-using-javascript) with the global tag, formatted like : `item = item.replace(/\/<.*>/, '')`, but that just outputs nothing.

Really lost here

Comment: Parsing html with regex is always a bad idea, there are better ways to parse them, like for your case `element.innerText` might be a better solution.

Comment: Hello, yes it's normal that it outputs an empty string. You just removed everything between the first opening bracket and the last closing bracket.

Comment: @LorenzMeyer Would it not remove each different cause individually?

Comment: If the string is indeed and HTML string, here's a general method to remove all text: https://jsfiddle.net/terrymorse/qy7ksap6/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just change your line of code by adding a `?`:

```
item = item.replace(/<.*?>/g, '')
```

While `.*` is a greedy match, `.*?` is ungreedy. Greedy means "match as much as you can". Ungreedy means "match as few as possible". Thus `<.*?>` will stop at the first closing bracket, and do what you want.

The second change to your code: add the `/g` modifier. In Javascript, `/g` means "match all occurences", while without, the regex only matches the first occurrence.

Comment: Why the downvote and the delete vote ? Yes there was a typo, but now it's corrected, and this answer does what the OP asked for, and gives additional explanations.

Comment: Awesome! That works, one note though there is an extra backslash
 ```item = item.replace(/\/<.*?>/g, '')```
 should be
```item = item.replace(/\<.*?>/g, '')```

Comment: I didn't do the downvote.