# How to remove a specific letter from a string

Tags: javascript

Add a removeLetter function that takes a string and a letter. The result of the function should be string, which does not have the specified character in letter.
How to do peple?

```
function deleteLetter(string, letter) {
  let final = '';
  for (let i = 0; i<string.length; i++) {
   if (string[i] === letter) {
     final.concat(string[i])
   }
   return final;
  }
}
```

Comment: What about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9932957/how-can-i-remove-a-character-from-a-string-using-javascript?

Comment: [String.prototype.replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

Answer (score 2):

You should return the result at the end of the function, not in the for loop

```js
function deleteLetter(string, letter) {
  let final = ""
  for (let i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
    if (string[i] !== letter) {
      final += string[i]
    }
  }
  return final
}

console.log(deleteLetter("asdasd", "a"))
```

Answer (score 1):

With ES2021 you'll be able to use [`String.replaceAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll) (already available on firefox stable (79) and chrome beta(85)/canary(86))

```js
console.log("test".replaceAll("t", ""))
```

Comment: you can see the compatibility here → https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es2016plus/#test-String.prototype.replaceAll

Comment: I'm using Chrome 84.0.4147.135 and got *"Uncaught TypeError: \"test\".replaceAll is not a function"*.

Comment: @Cid I missread the compatibility table, chrome only has it in beta (85) and canary (86) on chrome 84 you need to set a flag, modifying the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can just use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

```
let str = 'test'
let replaced = str.replace('e', '')
console.log(replaced) // tst
```

But remember that only first occurrence will be replaced when u use string as first parameter. Use regex solution when you want to remove all of the letters

Comment: Note that `replace` will only replace the first occurence, not all

Comment: Yeah, true. Forgot about it.

Answer (score 0):

```
const removeLetter = (str, letter) =>
  str.split('').filter(n => !n.includes(letter)).join('');

console.log(removeLetter('asd', 'a'));
```

or

```
const removeLetter = (str, letter) => str.replace(/[^letter]/, '');

console.log(removeLetter('asd', 'a'));
```

Comment: Why not splitting to the letter directly ?

Comment: the second one will only remove the first occurence of the letter

Answer (score 0):

using splice & indexOf

```js
function delLetter(word,letter){
  let wordArr = word.split('');
    let idx = wordArr.indexOf(letter);
    wordArr.splice(idx,1); // deleted here
  return wordArr.join('');
}

console.log(delLetter('twinkle','w'))
```