# How can i extract vowels in a Javascript String?

Tags: javascript, html, string, substring

If i have 'var' how can i get "e,o,o" out of it ?
With substring you can only get the position

```
var str = "Hello world!";
var res = str.substring(1, 4);
```

Comment: Check every character a.k.a. a loop.

Comment: do you mean from **"Hello word!"**  you want  **"Hll wrd!"**,  if yes, you have to check every char in the whole string if it is a vowel, delete it: [remove-a-character-from-a-string-using-javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9932957/how-can-i-remove-a-character-from-a-string-using-javascript)

Comment: Try this `var str = "Hello world!", vls={a:1,e:1,i:1,o:1,u:1}, res = str.split('').filter(ch => !!vls[ch]);` and close the question. You should research first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not entirely clear if you only want the vowels or if you want all except the vowels.  Either way, a simple regular expression can get the characters you need.

```js
let str = "Hello World";

let res = str.match(/[aeiou]/ig).join("");
console.log(res);

let res2 = str.match(/[^aeiou]/ig).join("");
console.log(res2);
```

Remove the `.join("")` part if you want an array, otherwise this gives you a string

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
var str = "Hello world!";
var theGoods = str.split('').filter(c => ['e', 'o'].includes(c)).join('');
```

Or if you wanted the 'inverse' behavior

```
var str = "Hello world!";
var theGoods = str.split('').filter(c => !['e', 'o'].includes(c)).join('');
```

Comment: 4 function calls, and two of them will iterate over the complete array/string, just to find a subset of vowels in a string

Comment: \o.o/ I don't know if thats a criticism - but I think it's beautiful. I'm sticking with it.

Answer (score 1):

You can loop the string and store those vowels in an array.

```
var arr = [];
for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++){
    if(str[i] == 'e' || str[i] == 'o'){
        arr.push(str[i]);
    }
}
console.log(arr);}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty easy to extract them, as long as you know RegEx (regular expression)

```js
var str = "Hello world!" // The original string
var res = str.match(/[aeiou]/gi).join("") // Extracting the vowels
// If you want to get the consonants, here you go.
var res2 = str.match(/[^aeiou]/gi).join("")
// Logging them both
console.log(res)
console.log(res2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function deletevowels(str) {
    let result = str.replace(/[aeiou]/g, '')
    return result
}
  
var text = "Hi test of Replace Javascript";
const a = deletevowels(text);
console.log(a);
```

Comment: The OP doesn't want to remove the vowels, does he?

Comment: i dont know, but it could be less useless

Comment: Please add an explanation to improve the insight