# How can remove page and pageSize from given text?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
 "?page=2&pageSize=12&query=hex"
```

I have the above text I want to remove page and pageSize along with value. After removing the page and pageSize my text should look like given below.

```
"?query=hex"
```

Comment: Maybe this answers your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9932957/how-can-i-remove-a-character-from-a-string-using-javascript

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `URLSearchParams` to remove params of the query:

```js
const queryString = "?page=2&pageSize=12&query=hex";
const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);

searchParams.delete("page");
searchParams.delete("pageSize");

const resultQuery = `?${searchParams.toString()}`;
```

Reference:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams

Answer (score 1):

here is my solution

```
text.replace(/(page=\d+&?)|(pageSize=\d+&?)/g, '')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way of doing it without any third-party library:

```js
const input = "?page=2&pageSize=12&query=hex"

const parts = input
  .replace(/^\?/, "")
  .split("&")
  .filter(p => !/^(page|pageSize)/.test(p))

const output = "?" + parts.join("&")

console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `regex` you can do that as below:

```js
const str =  "?page=2&pageSize=12&query=hex";

console.log(str.replace(/page.*&/g, ""));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, maybe this will help. Simple to implement and understand.

```js
var str = "?page=2&pageSize=12&query=hex";
var finalStr = '?' + str.substring(str.indexOf('query='))
console.log(finalStr)
```