# How to remove $ from javascript variable?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remove characters from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4846978/remove-characters-from-a-string)

I have a variable `p` which I would like to remove the `$` from. This variable will be a number such as `$10.56`. How can I do this? I thought it could be done using `.replace('$','')` but i'm not quite sure how to implement this.

Here is my javascript code:

```
function myFunction() {
  var p = parseFloat(document.getElementById('p_input').value);
  var q = parseFloat(document.getElementById('q_input').value);
  if (!q){
  document.getElementById('t').value = '';
  }
  else {
  var t = q * p;
  document.getElementById('t_output').value = t;
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you ever tried to do such string replace?

Comment: Did you try it ? `'$10.56'.replace('$','')`

Comment: The code you have provided is irrelevant to your question. Start with var p = "$10.56" and work from there.

Comment: `replace()`  returns the string with the replaced stuff. Have you tried `var newString = oldString.replace('$', '');` ?

Comment: `document.getElementById('p_input').value.substr(1)` ?

Comment: yes i did try it. But I didn't know where to put the replace part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, assuming that the values of p_input and q_input will be the money values:

```
var p = parseFloat(document.getElementById('p_input').value.replace('$', ''));
var q = parseFloat(document.getElementById('q_input').value.replace('$', ''));
```

Answer (score 6):

It's pretty simple:

```
var myString = "$15.62"
console.log(myString.replace('$', ''));
//Logs: "15.62"
```

Please note that this new value is not actually "saved" to `myString`, you'll have to assign it to a variable, yourself:

```
var newString = myString.replace('$', '');
```

Comment: +1 - you are  JavaScript genius!

Comment: @ColinE: Bow before the might of my loose typing! (thanks!)

Comment: @dystroy: Nitpicking, but you're right. Edited :P

Comment: @Cerbrus Frankly, you're answering a trivial question that was answered in comment before you. Nitpicking is kindof kind and the minimum we can do, don't you think ?

Comment: *places a wooden wing bow on the keyboard*